# Firebase storage for image uploads

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

Issue with Firebase storage for image uploads: “Storage bucket cannot be initialised with a path”

Occurs when we try when pulling the putData method

We tried the following:

```
storage.storage().reference().child("Images").child("image1.jpg")
reference().document(object.id).setData(data,merge:true)

storage.storage().reference().child("Images").child("image1.jpg")
reference().document(object.id).setData(data,merge:true)
```

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here.  It look like you're doing stuff with both Cloud Storage and Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have trouble storing the image, try this way

```
    let imageName = "image1.jpg"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)    
    let store = Storage.storage()        
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    let imageData: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!
    let storeRef = store.reference().child("Images")
    let _ = storeRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let _ = metadata else {
            print("error occurred: \(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
        let pat = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString.description)
        let link = pat! //Link of image

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this Error message, took me a few hours because it crashes the app every time.  Previously, I initialized my bucket for dev and prod using the full path, prefixed by `gs://`

Removed the gs:// and that fixed the problem:

Changed:

```
    if (Config.of(context).isDev) {
      FirebaseStorage.instance.bucket = "gs://dev-appname.appspot.com";
    } else {
      FirebaseStorage.instance.bucket = "gs://appname.appspot.com";
    }
```

TO:

```
    if (Config.of(context).isDev) {
      FirebaseStorage.instance.bucket = "dev-appname.appspot.com";
    } else {
      FirebaseStorage.instance.bucket = "appname.appspot.com";
    }
```